# Random Sequence samples with MatLab

Tags: matlab

i have a question. I need to generate a random sequence of data samples of increasing size from a specified normal distribution. This i think i am doing ok in my code

```
array1 = N;
array2 = zeros(1,1000);
array3 = zeros(1,1500);
normal_mu = 5;
normal_sigma = 3;
pd2 = makedist('Normal','mu',normal_mu,'sigma',normal_sigma);
N=2;
for i=1:500
    array1 = zeros(1,N);
    lastN = N;
for a=1:N
    array1(a)=random(pd2);
end
if i>1
for b= lastN-1:N
    array2(b) = random(pd2);
end
else
for b = 1:N
    array2(b) = array1(b);
end
Mean = mean(array2);
array3(i) = Mean;
N= N+2;
end
end
figure,plot(array3,'*');
```

The problem is the next bit. I have to start with a randomly generated first sample of n and each sample in the sequence should contain all the data values contained in the previous samples plus n further data values.

I Have no idea where to start with this, would appreciate any help with this at all!!

Comment: Maybe you are looking for some kind of concatenation to merge old and new samples? For example `cat(dim, A, B)` But I do not understand what the `rand(i)` is doing in your code...

Comment: Yeah that might be it, oh i forgot to remove the rand(i), yeah thats not meant to be there sorry